# Show that the edges of any graph G can be oriented such that no directed path of length $\chi(G)$ exists

Tags: graph-theory

$\chi(G)$ represents the minimum number of colors needed for the proper coloring of $G$.
The only thing I have noticed is that if we have $k=\chi(G)$ colors, then we have $k$ color classes, and that a path connecting one vertex from each color class has length $k-1$.

Comment: As a warm-up, try thinking about how you'd orient the edges of a bipartite graph such that there's no directed path with two edges. Then generalize.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Sorry I'm new to graph theory and have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Have you looked at any specific examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $V_i$ denote the subset of nodes colored $i$. Note that $V_i$ is an independent set. For every $i<j$, direct all edges between $V_i$ and $V_j$ towards $V_j$. Then each directed path will have at most $\chi(G)-1$ edges.